# iOS GCD global queue priority both 0.5

Tags: ios, dispatch

I met the problem is why the following code print out priority is the same?  Why is this? Thank you very much.

```
    print("main:\(Thread.current)")
    print("thread main priorities:\(Thread.current.threadPriority)")

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
        print("utility:\(Thread.current)")
        print("thread utility priorities:\(Thread.current.threadPriority)")
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        print("background:\(Thread.current)")
        print("thread background priorities:\(Thread.current.threadPriority)")
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
        print("userInteractive:\(Thread.current)")
        print("thread userInteractive priorities:\(Thread.current.threadPriority)")
    }

    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        print("userInitiated:\(Thread.current)")
        print("thread userInitiated priorities:\(Thread.current.threadPriority)")
    }
```

Log:

main:{number = 1, name = main}
thread main priorities:0.5

userInteractive:{number = 3, name = (null)}

utility:{number = 5, name = (null)}

background:{number = 6, name = (null)}

thread userInteractive priorities:0.5

userInitiated:{number = 4, name = (null)}

thread utility priorities:0.5

thread background priorities:0.5

thread userInitiated priorities:0.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the docs:

```
@available(iOS 4.0, *)
open var threadPriority: Double // To be deprecated; use qualityOfService below
```

threadPriority is deprecated. Also, Apple's GCD team has been very clear on the Thread - Queue topic. GCD will managed the threads for you. A queue priority is not a thread priority. Take a look at this example, which is the code you posted here, pretty much, I just added the "qos_class_self().rawValue", which is really how you should test the QoS, and not with the "threadPriority".

```
print("main:\(Thread.current), Thread main priorities:\(Thread.current.threadPriority), QoS: \(qos_class_self().rawValue)")

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
    print("utility:\(Thread.current), Thread utility priorities:\(Thread.current.threadPriority), QoS: \(qos_class_self().rawValue)")
}

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    print("background:\(Thread.current), Thread background priorities:\(Thread.current.threadPriority), QoS: \(qos_class_self().rawValue)")
}

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive).async {
    print("userInteractive:\(Thread.current), Thread userInteractive priorities:\(Thread.current.threadPriority), QoS: \(qos_class_self().rawValue)")
}

DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
    print("userInitiated:\(Thread.current), Thread userInitiated priorities:\(Thread.current.threadPriority), QoS: \(qos_class_self().rawValue)")
}
```

I also combined the prints per closure so they don't get scrambled in different lines in the log. This shows you that QoS is maintained, whereas threadPriority is deprecated.

```
main:<NSThread: 0x6100000762c0>{number = 1, name = main}, Thread main priorities:0.5, QoS: 33
userInteractive:<NSThread: 0x610000261fc0>{number = 4, name = (null)}, Thread userInteractive priorities:0.5, QoS: 33
utility:<NSThread: 0x618000079100>{number = 3, name = (null)}, Thread utility priorities:0.5, QoS: 17
userInitiated:<NSThread: 0x608000078380>{number = 5, name = (null)}, Thread userInitiated priorities:0.5, QoS: 25
background:<NSThread: 0x610000262000>{number = 6, name = (null)}, Thread background priorities:0.5, QoS: 9
```

So, in the end, the take away is not to think in terms of threads, but to think in terms of Queues, their QoS and knowing that GCD will manage threads for you. Very different concept to what we were used to before Queues came around with GCD.